# Замена переменной окружния PATH для клиента

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

На сервере установлены: Oracle Client 11g и Oracle Instant Сlient 12.2.

При замене пути в переменной среде PATH старые приложение не сломаются?

---

P.S. Я бы обновил клиент, но это вне моей рабочей зоны ответственности.

Comment: А какой версии сервер БД? Если это вне вашей рабочей зоны ответственности, то ничего менять не надо, пусть этим займутся, то кто в этом компитентен.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ответ на вопрос дан в самом вопросе:

> но это вне моей рабочей зоны ответственности

Ничего менять не надо.

Что-то менять в продуктивной среде, вкл. переменные окружения, могут только те, в чей круг обязаностей это входит и кто в этом компитентен.